# Angular 4 call a function within a <td>

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this piece of code:

**personListComponent.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of personService.getPersons()">
      <td (onShow)="getCountry(person)">{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{country}}
</tr
```

**personListComponent.ts**

```js
country : string = '';

getCountry(person : Person){
  this.country = this.countryservice.getCountry(person.countryid);
}
```

I want to get the country from the person and show it in the table, however `(onShow)` never calls `getCountry()` function.
Is there a way to call this function from within the `<td>` element? Or any way to show the country?

Comment: How does these methods look like in the service? I mean `getPersons` and `getCountry`?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to bind to functions in the view, because they are called every time change detection runs. It's better to assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using ngShow , you can directly evaluate a function inside the td as follows,

```
<tr *ngFor="let person of personService.getPersons()">
      <td>{{person.name}}</td>
      <td>{{getCountry(person) | async}}
</tr>
```

and the function as

```
getCountry(person : Person){
  return  this.countryservice.getCountry(person.countryid);
}
```

Comment: From `this.country = this.countryservice.getCountry(person.countryid);`, is the function returning an observable?